# Django import export add on existing admin

Tags: django

I am trying to use django import-export UI admin part. I can make it work in vanilla stage but when I want to implement it to admin I already have I get problems.

If we go with this example here 
https://django-import-export.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html#admin-integration

I am adding

```
class BookAdmin(ImportExportModelAdmin):
    resource_class = BookResource
```

and then I need to register that like

```
admin.site.register(Book, BookAdmin)
```

so it shows up, problem is that I already have this line above as I have a BookAdmin where I change how regular admin looks like

```
class BookAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
```

So I need to try to add import/export class with some different name like 
class BookAdminExport, but then I cant register it to admin anymore as if I try
 admin.site.register(Book, BookAdminExport) it says "The model book is already registered" so I dont have any ideas what to do next?

Comment: Have you tried just registering a single `BookAdmin` inheriting from `ImportExportModelAdmin` ? Is there any reason to register two book admin classes? Just add all the code from your other BookAdmin to the import-export admin class. The examples in the docs you link to looks like they are just _minimal_ examples. And `ImportExportModelAdmin` is a subclass of the django `ModelAdmin`.

Comment: Yes that is it. thanx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As https://stackoverflow.com/users/1977847/h%C3%A5ken-lid said

"Just add all the code from your other BookAdmin to the import-export admin class. The examples in the docs you link to looks like they are just minimal examples. And ImportExportModelAdmin is a subclass of the django ModelAdmin"

I was confused a bit with inheritance, didnt get that ImportExportModelAdmin is a sublcass of ModelAdmin and that I could code instead of

```
class BookAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
```

just

```
class BookAdmin(ImportExportModelAdmin):
```